# Flutter - Prompt for TouchID/FaceID when opening app

Tags: dart, flutter, touch-id, face-id

I'm having an issue implementing TouchID/FaceID Authentication in a way where it will automatically prompt the user when they open the app.  I am using the local_auth dependency for TouchID/FaceID.

In the code below, biometric authentication will pop up when the app resumes, but it is also impossible to dismiss. If you press the home button, it dismisses the TouchID prompt but immediately starts to try again, and causes an endless loop if you keep trying this.  It will also randomly prompt twice, so even if you successfully log in with the first TouchID prompt, it will pop up again immediately afterwards. Does anyone know of a way to fix this?  I also have a TouchID button on the login page that users can press to manually prompt TouchID, but I'd love to recreate how my banking apps and others work where TouchID prompts when you open the app automatically.

```
void initState() {
  super.initState();

  SystemChannels.lifecycle.setMessageHandler((msg) async {
    if (msg==AppLifecycleState.resumed.toString()) {
      // If can pop, app is not at login screen
      // so don't prompt for authentication
      if (!Navigator.canPop(context)) {
        if (_useFingerprint) {
          SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
          String password = prefs.getString('password');
          biometricAuthentication(_username, password);
        }
     }
  }
});

void biometricAuthentication(String user, String pass) async {
  print("Biometric Authentication Called");
  bool didAuthenticate = false;
  try {
    didAuthenticate = await localAuth.authenticateWithBiometrics(localizedReason: 'Please authenticate');
  } on PlatformException catch (e) {
    print(e);
  }

  if (!mounted) {
    return;
  } 

  if (!didAuthenticate) {
    return;
  }
  else {
    normalLogin(user, pass);   
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey Matt. Did you manage to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

Create a class for handle the life of your app

```
class LifecycleEventHandler extends WidgetsBindingObserver {
      final Function onResume;
    
      LifecycleEventHandler(this.onResume);
    
      @override
      Future<void> didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) async {
        switch (state) {
          case AppLifecycleState.resumed:
            onResume.call();
            break;
          default:
            break;
        }
      }
    }
```

Then in your main:

```
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addObserver(
      LifecycleEventHandler(() async {
        //Put your auth function here (biometric auth or passcode)
      }),
    );
  }
```

Every time you return to the application, the action you put will be executed

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  if (await _isBiometricAvailable()) {
    await _getListOfBiometricTypes();
    await _authenticateUser();
  }

  runApp(App());
}
```

Comment: This won't work as it only handles the case of the app starting for the first time, not resuming from background.

Answer (score 0):

I think I managed to solve it. If there are any other issues, let me know.

```
Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  bool isAuthenticated = await Authentication.authenticateWithBiometrics();

  if (isAuthenticated) {
   runApp(MyApp());
 } else {
   main();
 }
}
```

This seems to work every time I'm opening an app.
Moreover, here is my authentification.dart file

```
class Authentication {
  static Future<bool> authenticateWithBiometrics() async {
   final LocalAuthentication localAuthentication = LocalAuthentication();
   bool isBiometricSupported = await localAuthentication.isDeviceSupported();
   bool canCheckBiometrics = await localAuthentication.canCheckBiometrics;

   bool isAuthenticated = false;

   if (isBiometricSupported && canCheckBiometrics) {
     isAuthenticated = await localAuthentication.authenticate(
       localizedReason: 'Please complete the biometrics to proceed.',
       //biometricOnly: true,
       stickyAuth: true,
     );
   }

   return isAuthenticated;
 }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

**Disclaimer:** I have not much experience with iOS development, so I'm kind of extrapolating from Android here.

I believe the problem is that system dialogs make your app inactive, leading to an infinite loop of

1. the app gets resumed
2. the app displays a TouchID/FaceID dialog, thereby making itself inactive
3. the user confirming the dialog
4. your app coming to the foreground again, thereby *resuming*
5. see step 1

**Possible solutions**

- Don't ask for authentication on app startup, but rather when important actions are about to happen in the app. This is the way the authentication feature was intended to be used, so it's the most idiomatic solution. *(my favorite)*
- Set a time limit, like only show the dialog if the user was away for more than x seconds, thereby filtering out long inactive phases from short ones (including the one for authentication). *(feels like a workaround to me)*